# Large icons mess up layers panel

Tags: qgis, style

I'm observing the following annoying issue after styling layers by categories: All the categories show up on the Layers panel with a very large spacing between categories.
I'm not finding any settings to change this. Anyone seen and fixed this before ?

Please see attached image, for sure will help to understand the issue.

Using 
QGIS version 3.10.1-A Coruña

[image]

Comment: Did you use a geometry generator for your style? It's a known issue that geometry generator styles cause the legend/TOC entries to expand unnecessarily

Comment: Which unit is your line-width based on?

Comment: simple normal styling - width 0.26000